# Using FunSuite to test Spark throws NullPointerException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scalatest

I would like to use [FunSuite](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.1/index.html#org.scalatest.FunSuite) to test my [Spark](https://spark.apache.org) jobs by extending FunSuite with a new function, called `localTest`, that runs a test with a default SparkContext:

```
class SparkFunSuite extends FunSuite {

  def localTest(name : String)(f : SparkContext => Unit) : Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(name).setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    try {
      this.test(name)(f(sc))
    } finally {
      sc.stop
    }
  }
}
```

Then I can add tests easily to my testing suites:

```
class MyTestSuite extends SparkFunSuite {

  localTest("My Spark test") { sc =>
    assertResult(2)(sc.parallelize(Seq(1,2,3)).filter(_ <= 2).map(_ + 1).count)
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I run the tests I get a `NullPointerException`:

```
[info] MyTestSuite:
[info] - My Spark test *** FAILED ***
[info]   java.lang.NullPointerException:
[info]   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.defaultParallelism(SparkContext.scala:1215)
[info]   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.parallelize$default$2(SparkContext.scala:435)
[info]   at MyTestSuite$$anonfun$1.apply(FunSuiteTest.scala:24)
[info]   at MyTestSuite$$anonfun$1.apply(FunSuiteTest.scala:23)
[info]   at SparkFunSuite$$anonfun$localTest$1.apply$mcV$sp(FunSuiteTest.scala:13)
[info]   at SparkFunSuite$$anonfun$localTest$1.apply(FunSuiteTest.scala:13)
[info]   at SparkFunSuite$$anonfun$localTest$1.apply(FunSuiteTest.scala:13)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Transformer.scala:22)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
[info]   ...
```

What is causing the `NullPointerException`? Is my way to use Spark not correct in this context?

I'm using Scala 2.10.4 with `spark-core` 1.0.2 and `scalatest` 2.2.2.

Comment: If you call `.set("spark.default.parallelism", "n")`, where `n` is your number of cores, right after `setMaster`, does the NPE go away ?

Comment: @huitseeker same error. I don't know exactly what is null...

Comment: Spark's own unit tests use a similar pattern (we use ScalaTest's BeforeAndAfterAll and BeforeAndAfterEach traits for preforming this setup), so I'm surprised that this doesn't work.  Are you running multiple tests in parallel (e.g. do you ever have concurrently-running SparkContexts in the same JVM)?

Comment: No and I agree with you: Spark does something similar. What I have changed is how sc is created to avoid nulls in the code. This is so cryptic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this wasn't working is that I misused `FunSuite.test`. This method registers a new test when it is called, that is when `FunSuite` is constructed. The test will then be called when tests are run. But my `localTest` does some actions before and after calling `FunSuite.test`. In particular, after register the test with `this.test(name)(f(sc))`, it stops the `SparkContext`. When the test is called, `sc` is stopped and that causes the `NullPointerException` on the `taskScheduler` field of `SparkContxt`. The correct way to use FunSuite is:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext


class SparkFunSuite extends FunSuite {

  def localTest(name : String)(f : SparkContext => Unit) : Unit = {
    this.test(name) {
      val conf = new SparkConf()
        .setAppName(name)
        .setMaster("local")
        .set("spark.default.parallelism", "1")
      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
      try {
        f(sc)
      } finally {
        sc.stop()
      }
    }
  }

}

class MyTestSuite extends SparkFunSuite {

  localTest("My Spark test") { sc =>
    assertResult(2)(sc.parallelize(Seq(1,2,3)).filter(_ <= 2).map(_ + 1).count)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are running SparkContexts in more than one class, make sure that you put `parallelExecution in Test := false` in your build.sbt. I was running into the problem when I ran the command: `sbt test`. I would either get a `NPE` or a `PARSING_ERROR` caused by multiple SparkContexts running in the JVM.

Comment: awesome - I was looking for this.

Comment: This needs to be somewhere prominent in the Spark testing literature